# Complex matrix times complex vector question?

Tags: linear-algebra

With $i^2 = -1$, the product of $(A+iB)$ and $(x+iy)$ is $Ax+iBx+iAy-By$. Use blocks to separate the real part without $i$ from the imaginary part that multiplies $i$:

[image]

Comment: What's the difficulty? Do you know what's meant by "the imaginary part" in this question?

Comment: Hint: A complex number $a+bi$ can be regarded as a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I thought the answer is iB, iA. But the answer is B, A

Comment: Why a+bi can be expressed in this matrix?

Comment: Do you have a question?  If so, what is that question?

Comment: @MarkViola my questions is why a complex number a+bi can be regarded as a matrix(a, -b; b,a) Like the above comment

Comment: The imaginary part of, say, $3+4i$ is $4$, not $4i$. That's why the answer is $B,A$, not $iB,iA$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you! In the solution, it says "Complex matrix times complex vector needs 4 real times real multiplications." What does this mean?

Comment: I suppose it means to calculate $(a+ib)(c+id)$ you need to calculate $ac,ad,bc$ and $bd$.

Comment: Understood, Yao Zhao?

Comment: Yes. Thank you, Gerry Myerson.